# What's the expected value of Y for this?

Tags: statistics, random-variables, expected-value

Boston and Toronto play a series of basketball games.  Suppose game results are independent,both teams are equally good, and there are no ties, so each game is like a fair coin flip.  The teamskeep playing until one team has won four games.  Let $Y$ be the total number of games the teams play(so the possible outcomes of $Y$ are $4, 5, 6,$ and $7$.)  What is the expected value of $Y$?  (Hints: $Y$ isn’t binomial.  You might try a counting method.)

Comment: The hints you were given are the right ones.  Just go step by step from there.  What, for example, is the probability that $Y=4$?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Explaining it would be useful to see where you are stuck so that we can help you ( you can edit your question)

Comment: $E=\sum_{k=4}^7 kP_k$, where $P_k=P(Y=k)$

Comment: If you buy a lottery ticket for a single prize there are only two outcomes:  you win or you lose.  Do you suppose that means that there is a $\frac 12$ chance of winning?

Comment: More broadly, there is no reason to guess here.  You can simulate this game just by tossing a coin.  Do you think you get $HHHH$ on the first four tosses with probability $\frac 14$?  Try it and see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, $Y \in  \{4,5,6,7\}$ as suggested in the text.

Now we calculate the probability that the first team wins for each possible number of matches and then, because the problem is simmetric, we will need to multiply by $2$ .

The  last match has to be won by the first team while the other $3$ matches can be in any order between the previous games so you can use the binomial distribution here, you should obtain that for $Y=k$ such that $4 \leq k \leq 7$ you have

$$p_k = {k-1 \choose3}\frac{1}{2^{k-1}} \cdot \frac{1}{2} $$

Now you shouldn't have problems to calculate the expected value given by

$$E[Y]=\sum_{k=4}^7 k\cdot 2p_k = \sum_{k=4}^7 k{k-1 \choose3}\frac{1}{2^{k-1}}  $$